# Printer not recognized on Ubuntu Libre Office

Tags: 14.04, wireless, printing, libreoffice

I am running 14.04 and have a HP Deskjet 2545 wireless printer which is supported by Ubuntu.
I have run HpLIP, the latest version and installed the printer.

The printer is recognised by Ubuntu, printer and network, but LibreOffice do not see the printer. Only a Generic printer.

I don't know what to do anymore and would like to get some good advice

Comment: Can you please open a terminal window and run the following command and get the output here, `sudo apt-get install hplip`

Answer (score 1):

On behalf of OP:

I have solved the problem myself!!!

I forgot to run hp-setup 192.168.1.102 as requred by Hplip!!!!!